# Android Drawable (Progress Bar, Switch) rendering issue

Tags: android, eclipse, android-drawable, android-5.0-lollipop, xml-drawable

I am trying to implement the below UI. I am using Eclipse with ADT plugin.

[image: Spotify UI]

The below is the implementation of the circle [White + Dark Gray] (circle_shape.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@android:id/background">
        <shape android:shape="ring" android:innerRadius="65dp" android:thickness="10dp"
            android:useLevel="false">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
        <shape android:shape="ring" android:innerRadius="57dp" android:thickness="8dp" android:useLevel="false">
            <solid android:color="#FF393939" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

and the progress bar [Green] (circle_progress_bar.xml)as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:fromDegrees="270" android:toDegrees="270">
    <shape android:innerRadius="65dp" android:shape="ring" android:thickness="10dp">
        <gradient android:angle="0" android:endColor="#FF00FF00" android:startColor="#FF00FF00" android:type="sweep" android:useLevel="false" />
    </shape>
</rotate>
```

In the layout xml file as :

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/repeat"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="36dp"
    android:background="@drawable/circle_shape"
    android:indeterminate="false"
    android:max="100"
    android:progress="65"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/circular_progress_bar" />
```

**Problem 1:**
           The above code gives me exact shape as I want, but only with API 19 and API 20. As soon as I switch the preview mode in Eclipse to API 21, the progressDrawable seems to fill up the full circle leaving up only single circle filled up with green colour. I am not able to figure how to do the same on Android L.

**Problem 2:**
          This is related to the switch buttons. In API 21, I can easily set

```
<android:textOn="" android:textOff="">
```

and the buttons look fine. However, if I view the same in API19, the Thumb drawable becomes distorted (squeezed) until I set some text using textOn and textOff attributes.

Can someone please help me with the same?

Please feel free to move / close the question if it doesn't seems constructive enough. But Kindly be kind to redirect me to some other helpful resource.

**Edit 1**:
The below is the screen shot for **Problem 2**
[image: API 19 and API 21 Comparison]

The XML for switch goes as following:

```
<Switch
        android:id="@+id/switch1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/repeat"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/repeat"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="@drawable/toogle_selector"
        android:checked="true"
        android:thumb="@drawable/circle_1"
        android:track="@drawable/transparent"
        android:textOn=""
        android:textOff=""/>
```

Comment: Thanks for edit @Luciano Rodríguez

Comment: show the screenshot for API 21, it would be better if you give two screen shots of API 20 and API 21 side by side.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Found the solution to your problem

in "Circular_progress_bar"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromDegrees="270"
    android:toDegrees="270" >

    <shape
        android:innerRadius="65dp"
        android:shape="ring"
        android:thickness="10dp"
        android:useLevel="true" >
        <gradient
            android:angle="0"
            android:endColor="#FF00FF00"
            android:startColor="#FF00FF00"
            android:type="sweep"
            android:useLevel="false" />
    </shape>

</rotate>
```

**Because**
*android:useLevel="true"* is by default **false** is API Level 21

**Before** 
[image]

**After** 
[image]

Comment: Excellent!! Thanks a lot. Do you have any idea about the second problem?

Comment: I am just waiting for the solution to my second problem. Don't want to be mean but that's still half of the answer. :) I'll accept your answer if not able to find out the answer for same.

Comment: ohh, never seen your second one. Explain the issue.

Comment: <Switch
        android:id="@+id/switch1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/repeat"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/repeat"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="@drawable/toogle_selector"
        android:checked="true"
        android:thumb="@drawable/circle_1"
        android:track="@drawable/transparent"
        android:textOn=""
        android:textOff=""/>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65685/discussion-between-trivalent-and-murtaza-hussain).